# Monitoring what forms are being used in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2016, iis-8

We have been running an ASP.NET 4.5 web forms application with a SQL Server 2k16 database and we've been having some performance issues.  I have been using Query Store to identify some of the back end bottlenecks but we while monitoring the server we're seeing a lot of disk activity on the web side.  The application uses a lot of images and data and I'm wondering if it has something to do with some large jobs running.

When we experience the issue in our production server I can run SQL Profiler to grab the SQL calls but I'm not sure how to monitor on our windows server or in IIS what forms are being called at a particular time.  Is there something in Windows, IIS, or an inexpensive 3rd party tool that will show me exactly what forms are being requested during a period of time?  I would love to see the data going back and forth and identify the users as well.

Comment: Sounds like a job for some tracing/profiling code in your forms or form base class

Comment: The IIS logs would be the first place to start. Microsoft's LogParser tool can help you analyse them. If that doesn't tell you enough then you'll have to start instrumenting the application itself with some more specific analytics tooling

Comment: As far as I know, one asp.net page will just contains just one form tag, so you could check the IIS log file to find out the request send to which page.That page means it send to which form. Then you could check the sql profile's query happened time to find out the related sql query.